# How to know, which app is playing music in the background?

Tags: music, background-process

I installed some alarms, then I configured them... then I configured the phone settings the standard wake signal for a long music.

I ended up that something is playing music in my ear, in the background, and I have no way to know, which app is doing it.

Comment: check music,audio or any kind of media is playing or not using tasker https://taskernet.com/shares/?user=AS35m8nYj7A5qrPTA086ys%2FsiKF8MuaE80lm%2BmVtRU%2FYEwNLoBUZyPn4XVlnaNQa5BUwd%2B2PcHapfR0%3D&id=Project%3AmediaPlayingStatus

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this command inside adb shell
`dumpsys media_session | grep -E "Media button session is.*userId=0"`

It will output like this

```
blueline:/ $ dumpsys media_session | grep -E "Media button session is.*userId=0"
  Media button session is com.bsbportal.music/media_session (userId=0)
```

Here is a single liner command for getting the package name of app playing the audio

`dumpsys media_session | grep -E "Media button session is.*userId=0" | sed "s/.*Media button session is//g" | cut -d'/' -f1 | xargs`

```
blueline:/ $ dumpsys media_session | grep -E "Media button session is.*userId=0" | sed "s/.*Media button session is//g" | cut -d'/' -f1 | xargs
com.bsbportal.music
blueline:/ $ dumpsys media_session | grep -E "Media button session is.*userId=0" | sed "s/.*Media button session is//g" | cut -d'/' -f1 | xargs
com.google.android.youtube
blueline:/ $
```

If you've paused the Music playing apps then you would get the same above output.

If you really wanna confirm if the audio/music or some content is really being played then you can combine the above command with another one to check its playback state.

`dumpsys media_session | grep -E "Media button session is.*userId=0" -A11 | grep "state=" | sed "s/.*{state=//g" | cut -d ',' -f1`

Returns "3" for playing state and "2" for paused state.

```
blueline:/ $ dumpsys media_session | grep -E "Media button session is.*userId=0" -A11 | grep "state=" | sed "s/.*{state=//g" | cut -d ',' -f1
2
blueline:/ $
```

*All my tests were done on Google Pixel 3 running on Android 12, the shell commands might return a different output on different Android versions so make sure to fine tune them. (Or revert back to me if you need any help)*